# Can I mount volume to Katib Experiment?

Tags: go, kubeflow

I am using the .yaml file below to create Katib Experiment in Kubeflow. However, I am getting

> Failed to reconcile: cannot restore struct from: string

errors. Have any solutions for this? Most of the Katib Experiment example codes doesn't have a volume in it, but I'm trying to mount a volume after downloading the data from my S3.

```
apiVersion: "kubeflow.org/v1alpha3"
kind: Experiment
metadata:
  namespace: apple
  labels:
    controller-tools.k8s.io: "1.0"
  name: transformer-experiment
spec:
  objective:
    type: maximize
    goal: 0.8
    objectiveMetricName: Train-accuracy
    additionalMetricNames:
      - Train-loss
  algorithm:
    algorithmName: random
  parallelTrialCount: 3
  maxTrialCount: 12
  maxFailedTrialCount: 3
  metricsCollectorSpec:
    collector:
      kind: StdOut
  parameters:
    - name: --lr
      parameterType: double
      feasibleSpace:
        min: "0.01"
        max: "0.03"
    - name: --dropout_rate
      parameterType: double
      feasibleSpace:
        min: "0.005"
        max: "0.020"
    - name: --layer_count
      parameterType: int
      feasibleSpace:
        min: "2"
        max: "5"
    - name: --d_model_count
      parameterType: categorical
      feasibleSpace:
        list:
        - "64"
        - "128"
        - "256"
  trialTemplate:
    goTemplate:
        rawTemplate: |-
          apiVersion: batch/v1
          kind: Job
          metadata:
            name: {{.Trial}}
            namespace: {{.NameSpace}}
          spec:
            template:
              spec:
                volumes:
                - name: train-data
                  emptyDir: {}
                containers:
                - name: data-download
                  image: amazon/aws-cli
                  command:
                  - "aws s3 sync s3://kubeflow/kubeflowdata.tar.gz /train-data"
                  volumeMounts:
                  - name: train-data
                    mountPath: /train-data
                - name: {{.Trial}}
                  image: <Our Image>
                  command:
                  - "cd /train-data"
                  - "ls"
                  - "python"
                  - "/opt/ml/src/main.py"
                  - "--train_batch=64"
                  - "--test_batch=64"
                  - "--num_workers=4"
                  volumeMounts:
                  - name: train-data
                    mountPath: /train-data
                  {{- with .HyperParameters}}
                  {{- range .}}
                  - "{{.Name}}={{.Value}}"
                  {{- end}}
                  {{- end}}
                restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954467/how-to-mount-pvc-to-a-katib-job-specification/72957957#72957957), the following works for me:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: training-container
          image: docker.io/romeokienzler/claimed-train-mobilenet_v2:0.4
          command:
            - "ipython"
            - "/train-mobilenet_v2.ipynb"
            - "optimizer=${trialParameters.optimizer}"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/
              name: data-volume
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
          - name: data-volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: data-pvc
```